# Can't rotate or move view with mouse wheel

Tags: 3d-view, interface, camera

i don't know if i pressed something or not but for some reason i couldn't move using my mouse wheel. i can zoom in and out using the wheel but i can't rotate or move view. I tried looking at similar posts but they were very old and could not find out what they were meaning in my version of blender 2.8.

Answer (score 0):

Change your screen to some other window and then return , that solves the problem whenever i do that , by the way even i dont know what makes that happen

Comment: Do you mean for instance i could be on chrome looking for answers and come back to find this error gone?

Comment: yeah that happens with me